# generate xml string from entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How I can generate xml string from entity?

Comment: What is your 'Entity' ? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Hi, Entity is a database table.I am using entity framework which create .edmx file.in entity framework,each table is known as entity.I want to create xml string for each table in database. thanks pooja

Answer (score 1):

Use XmlSerialization and the XmlSerializer

[Example here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/xmlserializer_bulkload.asp)

Comment: XML serialisation is definitely the way to go.